# Hi How Can I Redirect To another page without reloading in browser in javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript developer
I'm new in javascript
Recently in my small project I got stuck with Redirect problems.
Basically i need to modify page without reloading or blue line in browser.
I just want to make sure that look like react which can do in javascript

Comment: You will need to push states and then render a page based on the state.

Answer (score -1):

For react you can use react-router https://reactrouter.com/

If your want to go with plain JS just change rendered DOM depending on `window.location` parameter.

Comment: No sir i want just vanilla js. no library

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).